# iFrameExtractor no ffmpeg with build_universal script

Tags: iframe, build, ffmpeg

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on how to extract the frames from an iphone video:

http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone#more-343

It says to do the following:

- open Terminal
- clone the repository: `git clone git://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor.git`
- go to the ffmpeg folder in the project: `cd iFrameExtractor/ffmpeg`
- build the ffmpeg libraries: `./build_universal`

So there's no ffmpeg folder in iFrameExtractor after cloning the repository so I went to the github page and it says to download the latest version of ffmpeg and move to to the ffmpeg folder (I presume it just means within iFrameExtractor):

- Download the latest ffmpeg (0.11.1 tested):
  `git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git`

So I've done that but there's no file or directory when I try to run `./build_universal` and I can see that there isn't.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively I was also looking at just installing ffmpeg-ios and trying to extract the frames myself:

https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

and I've run the script so I've got that folder in my xcode project as well but I'm unsure on how to link it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you finish building FFMPEG with FFmpeg-iOS-build-script, the result should be an "FFmpeg-iOS" folder.

Copy the folder to iFrameExtractor project and make sure to setup the library path in "Build Setting".

[Library Path in Build Setting example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW3tq.png)

Also, the project seems lack of iconv library, needs to be added in "Build Phase", and bit code enabled (would caused the failure on building project) which should be turned off.

Currently I am using DFURTSPPlayer (based on iFrameExtractor but added audio support) with FFMPEG 2.6.9 (which can be changed in the script file) to receive audio and video streaming.

https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer